# V-I characteristics of a non linear, bilateral element

Tags: voltage, current, device-characteristics

My professor had told us that Bilateral elements have V-I characteristics which are symmetric about the origin.

In an exam, we were asked to draw the V-I characteristics of a *non linear, bilateral* element.

The given answer was:

[image]

Shouldn't "symmetric about origin" imply something like this?

[image]

Have I misinterpreted the term "symmetric about the origin"? I am fairly sure that in the normal context, this corresponds to curves like my second image.

Comment: Yes - I would agree to you. Second function is symm. to the origin. For example, the slope at the origin of both functions in the 1st figure is not identical.

Comment: What does searching on the internet tell you about this? I've never heard of the term but that shouldn't stop you searching for this.

Comment: There are different kind of symmetries, mainy odd symmetry (think x^3 or sinus) and even symmetry (think x^2 or cosinus). The second one is odd simmetry. The first one… well, I don't think is symmetric. The first one is neither bilateral nor symmetric, I'd classify it as unilateral non-linear.

Comment: I’d invent a classification of the 1st as a bipolar exponential conjugate with a PN or NPN type positive voltage controlled current sink to a Pch negative voltage controlled conductance.  The origin has 2 axes which makes the bilateral definition vague for symmetry

Answer (score 1):

I was unfamiliar with the term "bilateral", so I visited a few websites to learn about it, and they all agree with you.

Bilateral elements present the same resistance to current flow for some given current *in either direction*, which amounts to this algebraic relationship:

$$ V(I) = -V(-I)\\ \text{for } I < 0 $$

Bilateral behaviour is manifest in the characteristic curve as *180° rotational symmetry about the origin*, like this:

[image]

Your first image shows mirror symmetry about the line \$V=-I\$ (in red), which is not at all the same thing. That symmetry is a result of this unilateral I-V relationship:

$$
V(I) = -V^{-1}(-I) \\
\text{for } I < 0
$$

[image]

Here are a couple of sites I used, which support this:

[Classification of Element | Network Theory](https://electricalvoice.com/classification-of-element-network-theory/)

[Active,Passive,Linear,Non-Linear,Unilateral, Bilateral Elements](https://circuitspedia.com/active-and-passive-devices-unilateral-bilateral-linear-element/#4_Unilateral_and_Bilateral)